# Scala can not load file in the interpreter

Tags: scala

I am doing the Scala course from Coursera; currently, I am at the week 2 exercises. I want to load the code into the interpreter so I can check the methods I implemented like this:

```
:load FunSets.scala
```

However, I get the following error:

```
<console>:10: error: not found: value common
       import common._
```

This appears because the source file imports another package like this:

```
package funsets

import common._
```

How can I make the interpreter see the other package as well?
Is there a way of importing the entire project?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your project uses sbt, you should be able to do the following.

1. From the root of your project, type `sbt` and press enter. Your project will be loaded in `sbt`.
2. Use the `console` task to load the REPL with all compiled classes and libraries. Use the `consoleProject` task to load the REPL with access to the project definition and sbt.

The [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#Configuration-level+tasks) has more details.